# Proving that AM contained in Pi_2

Tags: complexity-theory, complexity-classes

i think that it's true that AM is contained in $\Pi_2$ but I'm not sure how to prove it.  How do I prove that $AM \subseteq \Pi_2$?

Comment: 1. What have you tried? What approaches have you tried, for trying to prove this? Where did you get stuck? Why do you think it's true? What research have you done?  2. You can [use LaTeX](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands) for mathematics.

Comment: This is proved in the same way as for BPP (also contained in $\Pi_2$). Both are standard results that can be found in textbooks and online lecture notes, and even Wikipedia.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus : ​ ​ ​ That depends on one's initial definition of AM. ​ If private coins are allowed, then approximate counting is needed. ​ Allowing any constant number of rounds makes things still harder, though not by as much. ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @Ricky Demer The definition we used is with public coins. And I am having a hard time proving that. Can use some help

Comment: Does your definition allow any constant number of rounds, or restrict to [verifier sends random coins, prover sends response, verifier gives output]? ​ If the later, does your definition let the verifier use more random coins in its last phase? ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @Ricky Demer it's the later, and the definition doesn't specifically specify that it allows that behavior. There is no special mention of the final round - just that it's the stage in the interactive protocol that the verifier either accepts or rejects the input.

Comment: Well, one would handle last-phase randomness with the same strategy as the ​ [BPP ⊆ P/poly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P/poly#Adleman.27s_theorem) ​ proof. ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: scifie, we prefer that you don't leave clarifications only in the comments. Given that part of our goal is to build an archive of high-quality questions and answers, we prefer that you edit your question to include all relevant information (including things like what definitions you are using if there's any possibility of ambiguity, what approaches you've considered, what you're specifically stuck on or what specific challenges are giving you difficulty).  People shouldn't have to read the comments to understand what you're asking.  Also, comments are transient and can disappear at any point.